# Linq- How to get unmatched records based on multiple fields from two collections

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get unmatched records between two collection based on multiple fields.

```
 public class Emp
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

public IList<Emp> GetMasterDetails()
    {
        IList<Emp> masterList = new List<Emp>            
        {
            new Emp { Id = 952491, Name = "Z005HY11", Amount = 500 },
            new Emp { Id = 952491, Name = "Z005H717", Amount = 500 },
            new Emp { Id = 1191676, Name = "Z005H717", Amount = 400 }                
        };
        return masterList;
    }

    public IList<Emp> GetNonMasterDetails()
    {
        IList<Emp> nonMasterList = new List<Emp>            
        {
            new Emp { Id = 952491, Name = "Z005H717", Amount = 500 },
            new Emp { Id = 1191676, Name = "Z005H717", Amount = 500 },
            new Emp { Id = 1227997, Name = "Z005HY11", Amount = 400 }
        };
        return nonMasterList;
    }


}

 Emp obj = new Emp();
        IList<Emp> masterList = obj.GetMasterDetails();
        IList<Emp> nonMasterList = obj.GetNonMasterDetails();
        var first = masterList.Where(p => !nonMasterList.Any(l => p.Id == l.Id || p.Name ==l.Name)).ToList();
        var second = nonMasterList.Where(p => !masterList.Any(l => p.Id == l.Id || p.Name == l.Name)).ToList();
```

I am trying above lambda but its not working. Whats wrong I am doing here? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working good. Unmatched records where the Id or the Name are equals. Maybe you are searching for Unmatched records where the Id **AND** (&&) the Name are equals. Or just the ID or just the Name **XOR**(^).

Just replace **||** with **&&** and see if that's is what you want.

**Tips for your questions:**

Clear your tags. This question is not about asp.net nor wpf. Is just linq, c# and boolean expressions. Also, be clear in your proposite.

> Say, I want the unmatched records. Two records match when its Ids and Its names are equal.

Comment: Sorry for Article. I have updated data in the question and its not working.

Comment: What data do you expect? The && helped you?

Comment: Your OR condition p.Id == l.Id || p.Name == l.Name return true when either  the Id or the Name are equal. All the data in your list have a equal record in the other one  using this condition.

Comment: Both expression should return a result here because we are checking if either ID or Name are different it should return result.

Comment: No, you are searching where there aren't a record with either the same ID or the same Name.